# How to Display a video in jsp by passing Url of the video

Tags: jsp

I want to play a video in view(HTML) by passing URL as a input how can I do that?

I have a `url` like

```
 /ui/UploadedImages/Wildlife.wmv
```

by passing this url to `jsp` I want to play a video

Comment: you want to use some video player ?

Comment: No without video player i have to play..

Comment: add a html video tag..but I am not sure it supports wmv format

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Video - How It Works

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

View this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

But for `wmv` format please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459949/876739)