# Video is not showing up in html stays blank or black

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I am currently creating. I have the video ready to go. But nothing I do gets rid of the black/blank screen I am getting. Any suggestions? Here is the code I am working with

```
<video width="400" height="400px" autoplay="" loop="" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4">
    <source src="ttsvideo.wmv">
    </video>
```

Comment: Please ensure consistency in the width and height, use px in both. What do you see if you open the page console?

Comment: Try using `style="width: 400px; height: 400px"`. Does your network tab or console tab shows any errors? Maybe video is not found?

Comment: All I am getting now is a bar that shows the video is running but the video is not showing at all. No black screen just fully blank.

Comment: What does your console or network tab show? Does the video have sound, do you hear it?

Comment: The video has no sound. it does show up in an avast browser. in IE it says video aborted. I have checked the files many times and the file and ext is correct

Comment: try setting the type attribute in the source elements. For mp4 it is type="video/mp4"
WMV seems not to be supported yet: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459891/how-to-play-wmv-files-in-html5-video-player

Comment: Is this video locally hosted or are your pages already live on the internet? If you go to the video URL directly, say you are on http://test.com/test if you go to http://test.com/test/video.mp4 - Does it begin to download/play?

Comment: the site is live. go to toptiersteel.com. You can see exactly what the video is doing. I did change the code to reflect: ```<video width="400px" height="400px" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" controls >
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">```

Comment: Also confirmed that there is nothing wrong in the files that could cause the video to break